# Let $a_1,\ldots,a_n \in [0,1)$ and $P:=(1-a_1)(1-a_2)\ldots(1-a_n)$. Find good lower-bound for $P$ in terms of $\|a\|_\infty$ and $\|a\|_2$

Tags: real-analysis, upper-lower-bounds, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Let $a_1,\ldots,a_n \in [0,1)$, where $n>0$ is a large integer. Define $\|a\|_\infty := \max(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)$, $\|a\|_2 := \sqrt{a_1^2 + a_2^2+\ldots + a_n^2}$,  and $P:=(1-a_1)(1-a_2)\ldots(1-a_n)$.

> **Question.** Is there a better (larger is better) lower-bound for $P$ as a function of $\|a\|_\infty$ and $\|a\|_2$, apart from the trivial one $P \ge (1-\|a\|_\infty)^n$ ?

Comment: It's easy to show via induction that $P \ge 1-\|a\|_1$ where $\|a\|_1 = a_1+\cdots+a_n$. Do you necessarily need a lower bound in terms of $\|a\|_2$ and $\|a\|_{\infty}$?

Comment: Good point. But this bound can be arbitrarily bad compared to my trivial bound. Indeed consider $a = (1/n,\ldots,1/n)$. One has $1-\|a\|_1=0$, but $(1-\|a\|_\infty)^n=(1 - 1/n)^n \approx 1/e$. As for your second question, yes bounds in terms of $\|a\|_\infty$ and / or $\|a\|_2$ would be most desirable for my purposes :)

Comment: That's a good point. Also, the bound $(1-\|a\|_{\infty})^n$ can also be much worse than $1-\|a\|_1$. For instance, if $a = (1/2,0,0,\ldots,0,0)$, then $1-\|a\|_1 = 1/2$ but $(1-\|a\|_{\infty})^n = 2^{-n}$. I guess it really depends on whether the $a_k$'s are roughly the same magnitude, or not, which is very application dependent.

Comment: Yes, there are clearly different regimes, so ideally, we'd have something which smoothly interpolates between all these extremes. This would probably be a bound containing ratios of $\|a\|_1$, $\|a\|_2$, $\|a\|_\infty$ :)

Comment: Crazy idea: $P:= \Pi_{j=1}^n(1-a_j) \ge \Pi_{j=1}^ne^{-a_j/(1-a_j)} = e^{-\sum_{j=1}^na_j/(1-a_j)} \ge e^{-\sum_{p=1}^\infty\|a\|_p^p}$, where I've used the fact that

$$
\sum_{j=1}^na_j(1-a_j)^{-1} = \sum_{j=1}^na_j(1+a_j+a_j^2+\ldots) = \sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{p=1}^\infty a_j^p = \sum_{p=1}^\infty\sum_{j=1}^na_j^p = \sum_{p=1}^\infty\|a\|_p^p.
$$

This gives nontrivial bounds in both regimes :)